# Checkbox retaining its false attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a popup, on the click of `Save User` i am saving a value and want to reset a form in a more generic way, so i tried using that and was successful in case of resetting the `textbox, dropdown` but when it came to `checkbox` i am facing a little trouble, i am using the below code to reset all the checkboxes:

```
$('#' + form).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
    this.checked = false;
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('#' + form).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked", false);
```

both of the above code fails in case when i try to re-add a new user, in this case, when i checks the checkbox and found that, even after i have checked the checkboxes they all are in false state and on the form submission there values are not picked up.

But when i use:

```
$('input[name=storeList]').removeAttr('checked');
```

This code runs successfully and later on re-submission values of checkboxes are picked up accordingly.

This seems weird to me and might be to you also, but this is happening and even i dnt know why. Please help me

**Note** Second time checkbox shows `blank` value when i alert the value of checkbox.

Comment: What value is held by `form` in your code?

Comment: It shows up `blank` when i alert the checkbox value..

Comment: Is it in every browser?

Comment: @Vlad it is in every browser

Comment: Make sure that `form` holds the id of your HTML form, as a string, so that, when combined with a leading hashtag, it forms a valid selector.

Comment: @MichaelZalla the form is working fine for every other control, i can say i have dropdowns, textboxes and other controls on form but when it  comes to checkbox the code stops working

Comment: I don't understand why you are passing in a second argument to [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/), which only expects a single argument (see your second bit of code)

Comment: use prop in place of removeAttr
$('#' + form).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').prop("checked", false);

Comment: @MichaelZalla i have tried using the both way, both way seems to be not working

Comment: @Exlord no its also not working

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$('#' + form).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is very familiar to me because i also have been stuck in these situations many times.Why don't you can just clear the form after the form has been saved.
Like this,
    $('form_id').form('clear');

And if possible cant u send the fiddle for this.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, but i have a div, can i use the save code to reset the div

Answer (score 0):

Looks like removeAttr() can not be reset by form.reset()

you can do this in the Following Ways :

1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all');
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
```

2)

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

3)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
{ 
        this.checked = false; 
});
```

4)

```
HTML

<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="checkall" />
JavaScript

$('#checkall:checkbox').change(function () {
   if($(this).attr("checked")) $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
   else $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});​
```